# How can i make a Screenshot in Flutter Web and send it to email?

Tags: flutter, email, web, screenshot

Make a Screenshot in Flutter Web and send it to email?
Normal Screenshot works on Mobile App but not in web.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot can be taken by default keys in any app but for sharing you can use the share package provided by flutter.
https://pub.dev/packages/share

Comment: I got it. Thank u very much :)

Comment: please mark the answer as correct, it will help me.